# HowTo disable Key Shortcut Alt + F4 (Closing app) for Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, shortcut-keys

since I want to reserve **Alt + F4** for my **Java** application, I need to find a way to disable it for the **Xubuntu 14.04** OS. Anyone any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Settings Manager -> Window Manager -> Second tab would be `keyboard` which will be containing shortcuts assigned, search for "close window" action and click on clear after selecting it.

Comment: You are awesome! WORKS perfectly! The World is not as bad as one would think.